# VBA array inverse

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, inverse

I am trying in Excel VBA to get some values from a spreadsheet in a square array invert this array. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim A As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
ReDim A(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Double

For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 3
        A(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value      
    Next j
Next i

A = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A)

End Sub
```

In the line:

```
A = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A)
```

I get the error:

> run-time error 1004: application defined or object defined error

Can anyone assist me on this?

Comment: What are the values in cells `A1:C3`?

Comment: [50 12 13]
[21 22 23]
[31 32 33]

Comment: I found my mistake. I had wrong the values of the matrix. Instead of using the above values i was using [11 12 13] [21 22 23] [31 32 33] from another matrix, which can not be inverted mathematically... Sorry for wasting your time but my mind was stuck for abt 2 hours. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be trying to invert an ill-conditioned matrix.  I tried your code on an easy example:

```
Sub dural()

    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    ReDim A(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Double

    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            A(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i

    A = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A)

    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            Cells(i + 5, j + 5).Value = A(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

and got:

[image]

which appears to be correct. *(the product of the two matrices is very  close to a unit matrix)*

Comment: You can skip the loops and write `A = Cells(1,1).Resize(3,3).Value`, but you have to declare `Dim A() as Variant` first. Also works in reverse `Cells(5,5).Resize(3,3).Value = A`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below to read a 3×3 array from cell `A1` and write the inverse on cell `A5`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim A() as Variant, B() as Variant
    A = Range("A1").Resize(3,3).Value
    B = WorksheetFunctions.MMinverse(A)
    Range("A5").Resize(3,3).Value = B
End Sub
```

There is no need to loop through each cell, which is a slow operation. Read and write whole tables with one command using the `Range().Resize().Value` syntax.